# Switching Observables

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, observable, reactive-programming

I have two observables `ob1` and `ob2`. Now I have to switch between `ob1` and `ob2` based on the condition that I should switch to `ob2` when `ob1` is not emitting and switch back to `ob1` when it starts emitting.

Comment: Ok. Where did you get stuck when you tried to implement this?

Comment: Detecting an observable is not emitting requires a timeout at least. Also what should happen to events of ob2 while ob1 is emitting? What is the original requirement you want to solve by this switching fashion?

Comment: Not sure what the original requirement is, perhaps just .merge() both and then .debounce(); it can happen though that ob1 events will be skipped sometimes, not sure whether it is critical to preserve them all.

Comment: Got the answer did debounce on first then takeuntil on the second with a repeat on it then merged both.